# Aggregate/Windowed Function To Find Min and Max of Sequential Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got a SQL table where I want to find the first and last dates of a group of records, providing they're sequential.

```
 Patient | TestType | Result |     Date
------------------------------------------
    1    |    1     |   A    |  2012-03-04
    1    |    1     |   A    |  2012-08-19
    1    |    1     |   B    |  2013-05-27
    1    |    1     |   A    |  2013-06-20
    1    |    2     |   X    |  2012-08-19
    1    |    2     |   X    |  2013-06-20
    2    |    1     |   B    |  2014-09-09
    2    |    1     |   B    |  2015-04-19
```

Should be returned as

```
Patient | TestType | Result | StartDate   |   EndDate
--------------------------------------------------------
   1    |    1     |   A    |  2012-03-04 | 2012-08-19 
   1    |    1     |   B    |  2013-05-27 | 2013-05-27
   1    |    1     |   A    |  2013-06-20 | 2013-06-20 
   1    |    2     |   X    |  2012-08-19 | 2013-06-20
   2    |    1     |   B    |  2014-09-09 | 2015-04-19
```

The problem is that if I just group by `Patient`, `TestType`, and `Result`,
then the first and third rows in the example above would become a single row.

```
Patient | TestType | Result | StartDate   |   EndDate
--------------------------------------------------------
   1    |    1     |   A    |  2012-03-04 | 2013-06-20 
   1    |    1     |   B    |  2013-05-27 | 2013-05-27
   1    |    2     |   X    |  2012-08-19 | 2013-06-20
   2    |    1     |   B    |  2014-09-09 | 2015-04-19
```

I feel like there's got to be something clever I can do with a partition, but I can't quite figure out what it is.

Comment: What determines the sequence or order of your records?  Rows by themselves don't have any order.  You need a column that defines the sequence.

Comment: Ordered by date, within the patient/type group.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. In your sample data, you presented 8 rows. It would seem that the order of those 8 rows is significant to determine how to calculate the results.  How are those 8 rows ordered?

Comment: There's no implicit order. I just picked that order because I thought it would make the problem clear.

Comment: Well, if there is no implicit order, then there is no guarantee that you'll get consistent results either regardless of how you choose to solve this problem.  A consistent and reproducible solution to your problem depends completely on the order of that initial data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this.  I like identifying the groups using the difference of row number values:

```
select patient, testtype, result,
       min(date) as startdate, max(date) as enddate
from (select t.*, 
             (row_number() over (partition by patient, testtype order by date) -
              row_number() over (partition by patient, testtype, result order by date)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by patient, testtype, result, grp
order by patient, startdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select patient, testtype, result, date as startdate, 
isnull(lead(date) over(partition by patient, testtype, result order by date), date) as enddate
from tablename;
```

You can use `lead` function to get the value of date (as enddate) from the next row in each group.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/55a9f/1) with sample data.

Comment: Your fiddle show extra rows. According to OP the result should group first two A because are together, then a single B, then a single A, then group both X and both B because are consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

See if this gives you what you need.

```
with T1 as (
  select
    *,
    case when lag(Patient,1)
           over (order by Patient, TestType, Result) = Patient
          and lag(TestType,1) 
           over (order by Patient, TestType, Result) = TestType
          and lag(Result,1)
           over (order by Patient, TestType, Result) = Result
    then null else 1 end as Changes
  from t
), T2 as (
  select
    Patient,
    TestType,
    Result,
    dt,
    sum(Changes) over (
      order by Patient, TestType, Result, dt
    ) as seq
  from T1
)
  select
    Patient,
    TestType,
    Result,
    min(dt) as dtFrom,
    max(dt) as dtTo
  from T2
  group by Patient, TestType, Result, seq
  order by Patient, TestType, Result
```

Comment: Note that my query and Gordon’s give different results if you add this row to your sample data: (1,1,'B','2013-05-27'). I’m not sure what you want as a result in that case.